# Use exact binomial distribution to find ....

Tags: statistics

A die is loaded so that the probability of rolling a two is only 1/10. Let y denote the number of twos rolled in 50 rolls of this loaded die.

Use exact binomial distribution to find $P(y≤5)$

Using a ti-84 I plugged in $binomcdf(50,1/10,5)$ for $binomcdf(trials, p, x)$ and got 0.616123 ...

But I am not sure if I am supposed to take that number and subtract it from one, if that is my answer, or if I am completely off. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Someone could answer if you included what the manual says about "binomcd(n,p,k)."

Comment: f(n,p,k) is the pmf of the distribution at x = k. You have computed this value for k = 5. The question asks for $x \le 5$. So you have to compute this value for all $k \le 5$ and then sum it up.

Comment: I just looked it up. The binomcdf(n,p,k) already finds prob(x less or equal k) so your result should not be subtracted from 1. If it were you'd be finding prob(x > k).

Comment: @Kaind, so would I do it for k = 1 - 4 also and add all those answer together?

Comment: If you use binompdfyou should add it up from 0 to 5. But if using binomcdf just use the 5.

Comment: @coffeemath, thank you I really appreciate it!

Comment: Using R code `pbinom(5,50,1/10)` also gives $0.616123$ which is  $\mathbb P(X \le 5)$ when $X$ has a binomial distribution with $n=50$ and $p=\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: @Hentry's R code is correct. You could get an approximate answer by doing the experiment with 50 rolls of this biased die a million times and finding the proportion of the times 5 or fewer `2`'s were seen: R code: `nr.2 = replicate(10^6,sum(sample(1:6, 50, rep=T, p = c(9,5,9,9,9,9))==2))`. Then `mean(nr.2 <= 5)`
returns $0.616317,$ which is accurate to about three places. The vector `c(9,5,9,9,9,9)` specifies the bias of the die.